# Process Dll Loading

Tags: winapi, process

I'm developing a security app that should block dll injection in the address space of some processes.
Let's say we a process in suspended state(which hasn't been initiliazed yet), is it possible to access the "list" of DLLs the process is going to load? I've tried the EnumProcessModules function but it doesn't seem to work(and I think it's pretty obvious, since the process is still in suspended state and hasn't loaded the DLLs yet). 
Moreover, I would like to change something in the DLL loading, for example let's say the process is going to load X.dll, Y.dll and Z.dll, is it possible to avoid the loading of Y.dll?

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: This question can't be answered until you explain the exact mechanism you are planning to use to meddle with it. Injected code? API's that peek and poke from another process?

Comment: I'm developing a security app, I want to prevent dll injection of some dlls in my process!

Comment: Please edit your question to clarify. You're busy accumulating answers that aren't going to help you.

Comment: "is it possible to access the "list" of DLLs the process is going to load?" You need a crystal ball :) Who knows what it may load in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load Dlls under program control then don't try to automatically load them using the dynamic linker. You're fighting against the design of the compiler.

Just don't link with the Dlls, but instead just include their headers, and load the Dlls manually with "LoadLibrary" and then get each function with "GetProcAddress".

Answer (score 0):

to retrieve a list of libraries that wold be loaded (including delayed loading) you'd need to walk the pe of the binary used for the process, the same way the windows loader would.

avoiding the loading of certain linked libraries becomes a lot more complex, as you will need to somehow fix any references to the symbols loaded from the library, which involves altering the IAT, to erase the links, then removing the dll link from the pe, then adjusting anything that referenced the now removed IAT entries.

this is a little easier with offline tools, such as LordPE, but its success and complexity ultimately depends on why you need to stop the dlls loading...

an alternative method is to use the windows debugger api to pause on dll load, the force an unload if it shouldn't be loaded(but this is also full of problems and will likely cause system locks and bsods)

Answer (score 0):

If, as per your comment, you are trying to produce a tamper-proof program ...
 can't make it completely tamperproof. If some human has access to log into the computer with enough access to set up code injection, sooner or later they can do anything they like. Injected code can certainly mess with the loader and replace dlls or block dlls. It can do anything.

Comment: I perfectly know this, but it's not a commercial app or something like that, I'm coding it just to study the inner workings of Windows Loader. Do you have any hints about how to accomplish this?